# How To Take Specific Letters Off A String

Tags: python

I am having difficulty creating a function that removes letters of "T" in two different ways. The `parameter` is a `Boolean`, if the parameter is `True` then it will print out a userinput (that is written in my code below) and it will keep asking that same input until the person types in "quit" and when the user does type in "quit" then it will take off all lower case "t" inside the string. If the `Boolean` is `False`, then the same process applies but instead of it taking out a lower case "t" it will take off a capital "T". Also, I want to keep the same type of format I written in my code below, thanks. Btw I am using python 2.4.

> ```
> def removeT(Boolea):
>     userInput=str(input("Enter a word/sentence you want to process: "))
>     while userInput:
>         string = (raw_input("Enter a word/sentence you want to process:"))
>         if Boolea == False:
>             userInput = userInput + string
>             while "T" in userInput:
>                 index = userInput.find("T")
>                 userInput = userInput[:index] + userInput[index+1:]
>         if string == "quit":
>             keepAsking = False
>             return userInput
>
>         else:
>             userInput = userInput + string
>             while "t" in userInput:
>                 index = userInput.find("t")
>                 userInput = userInput[:index] + userInput[index+1:]
>             while "T" in userInput:
>                 index = userInput.find("T")
>                 userInput = userInput[:index] + userInput[index+1:]
> ```

Comment: What does your code do now? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Well, when I type in a true or false to my function the input works fine but when I hit quit it gives an error

Comment: An important part of learning to program is learning what the error messages mean. "gives an error" is much less useful than the actual error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def removeT(b):
    s1 = ""
    while True:
        s2 = raw_input("Enter a word/sentence you want to process: ")
        if s2 == "quit": return s1
        s2 = s2.replace("T", "")
        if b:
            s2 = s2.replace("t", "")
        s1 += s2
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but it qives me a syntax error, I am currently using python 2.4

Comment: @A.R.S. the last line -- conditional expressions weren't introduced until 2.5

Comment: When I try runing the module it says "there is an error in your program, syntax error"  and it highlights the "if" in the very last line

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much it works but for the True it needs to filter out both capital and lower case "t" do I just add a t next next to c = "T" , "t" ?

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that. See the edit above - let's see if I finally got it right! :-P

Comment: Yup, its right, but unfortuantely it doesn't do exactly as I want it to do. Its a pretty detailed orientated code but I do appreciate the help. I am gonna use your code and try to add more to it so it can do what I want it to do. : ) Thanks a bunch!